# Get the SourceRange of explicit template instantiations using clang AST library

Tags: c++, abstract-syntax-tree, libtooling

In the following c++ source file:

```
1 //file my_func.cpp
2 void template<typename Bar> foo(Bar& bar) {
3     // some code
4 }
5 template void foo<double>(double&);
```

I want to get the beginning and the end of the explicit instantiation of the function template `foo` in form of a `clang::SourceLocation`.

I have tried:

```
clang::FunctionDecl* FS; //the AST node for the foo<double> function obtained by some AST matcher
if(const clang::FunctionTemplateSpecializationInfo* TSI = FS->getTemplateSpecializationInfo()) {
    clang::SourceLocation = TSI->getPointOfInstantiation();
}
```

This location will be line 5 and column 15 (the begin of "foo").
I have not found a way to obtain the begin of the complete explicit instantiation and the end.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I would like to know the same. In my case, `FS->isTemplateInstantiation()` returns `false` and `getTemplateSpecializationInfo` returns `nullptr` 

Comment: I asked the same in the clang discord. It seems that this information cannot be queried. One has to add this already in the clang-sema library to store the relevant information in the AST.